# L5 | Relationship Tinker Query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've setup a one to many relationship with the following models Job and Steps. A job can have many steps, and Step belongs to Job. When I go to query the relation with `Job::with('steps')->find(1)`, the results is displayed as expected with the collection

```
<MariasApp\Job #000000002b07ae180000000036b76e17> {
       id: 1,
       number: 59221,
       customer_id: 5,
       user_id: 17,
       created_at: "2015-03-24 01:32:20",
       updated_at: "2015-03-24 01:32:20",
       steps: <Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection #000000002b07ae070000000036b76e17> [
           <MariasApp\Step #000000002b07ae7b0000000036b76e17> {
               id: 37,
               job_id: 1,
               body: "Eligendi reiciendis ratione labore sed.",
               created_at: "2015-03-24 01:32:21",
               updated_at: "2015-03-24 01:32:21"
           }
       ]
   }
```

But when I run `Job::with('steps')->find(1)->body` I get a response `null`. Is there any way for me to pull just the `body` from the relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to get `body` from the steps collection. You need to specify which step you're trying to work with. Either use the first one

`Job::with('steps')->find(1)->steps->first()->body`

or something like this to loop through them

```
$steps= Job::with('steps')->find(1)->steps->all();

foreach($steps as $step){
    echo step->body;
 }
```

or to cycle through many jobs and get the first step of each one:

```
$jobs = Job::with('steps')->get();

foreach($jobs as $job){
  echo $jobs->steps->first()->body;
}
```

Comment: So that was it, but I have a table with 50 Jobs, so i don't want to limit the result to one Job ID. This doesnt seem to work `Job::with('steps')->get()->steps->first()->body`